# Time taken to process each item in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array `A` of positive numbers, a processor reads items from this array. For each read operation it takes 1 minute, and the item value is decremented and placed back in array if its value is more than zero.

Now find the sum of the total time taken for each element in array to process.

**Example:**

```
Array = [3,1,2], I am naming them as item0 = 3, item1 = 1, item2 = 2, for below explanation

Result = 13
```

**Explanation:**

```
Time 1, select item0, decrement 3 to 2 and placed at end of the array = [1,2,2]
Time 2, select item1, decrement 1 to 0, since it is zero this item is finished, not added to array = [2,2]

Time 3, select item2, decrement 2 to 1, put it in array = [2,1]
Time 4, select item1, decrement 2 to 1, put it in array = [1,1]
Time 5, select item2, decrement 1 to 0, item2 finished here, now array is [1]
Time 6, select item1, decrement 1 to 0, item1 is finished here, now array is []

Total time taken by each items is as follows
item0 took 6 minutes to finish
item1 took 2 minutes to finish
item2 took 5 minutes to finish

Total time taken = 6+2+5 = 13
```

**Constraints:**

```
Array length is 1 to 10^5
Each element in array range is 1 to 10^4
```

Here is my code:

```
public long solve(int[] arr) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int item : arr) {
        q.add(item);
    }   
    long time = 0;
    long result = 0;
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        int item = q.poll() -1;
        time++;
        if(item ==0) {
            result += time;
        } else {
            q.add(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In my code the while loop runs until each element becomes 0, I am not sure what is the Big O notation of time complexity.

I am looking for an optimized approach that takes less time

Comment: What other 'algorithms' have you thought about? What are the things you can change?

Comment: In the first operation, why did you "2 placed at end of the array"? Why not just put it back at index 0?

Comment: @Bohemian it seems clear from the code that each item is re-queued at the back after being "processed" (round-robin scheduling simulation).

Comment: @learner Why is total time not 6?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is completely trivial if the total time is required. It's just a sum of the array. To simulate the _actual_ code presented is more complicated. It can be done by recognizing that it takes `N` passes through the array to reduce each value by 1, so it takes `N * X + P` where `N` is the array size, `X` is the difference between the last value removed and the current value, and `P` is the position of the value.

Comment: Why do you keep adding `time` to `result` when `time` is actually the _total_ time taken so far? You should just return `time`. By the way, `LinkedList` is not efficient, if you're looking for a Queue that runs faster I suggest `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: @paddy, N is array size and P is position of each element, I am not able to understand what X, can you provide with an example

Comment: @paddy for input A=[3,1,2] the P values are [0,1,2] , X is last value removed then for A[0] = 3 last value removed is A[2] = 2, so difference is X = 3 -2 = 1. so the count for A[0] is N*X + P = 3 * 1 + 0 = 3. But A[0] takes 6 minutes to finish

Comment: @JimGarrison, I want to add the time taken for each item, so A[0] takes 6, A[1] takes 2, A[2] takes 5, add them 6+2+5 = 13

Comment: No, the total time is 6. Look at your example and the timings. You actually finish the whole array at time=6. Each line that says "Time=N" means that N minutes have elapsed since the start. If the total time is 13, what then is your processor actually doing between time=6 and time=13? Twiddling its thumbs?

Comment: You have an imaginary processor. The task is to imagine a processor that carries out these instructions. The "processor" could well be yourself with a pencil and paper. You're still "the processor". It doesn't have to be a CPU.

Comment: @learner Process 0 completed 3 units of task time at wall time 6; Process 1 completed 1 unit of task time at wall time 2; Process 2 completed 2 units of task time at wall time 5. The total amount of task time executed is 6. The wall time at which _all_ tasks were completed is 6.

Comment: @paddy, sorry what is wall time here

Comment: Think of a clock on the wall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to a variation of it wherein array elements are never removed nor moved to a different location in the array. The rules are as follows.

- M rounds take place, M being the largest element of the array, with each element of the array processed in turn in each round;
- at each step the element of the array being processed is reduced by one if it is positive and is left unchanged if it equals zero; and
- processing time is one minute for positive elements, zero minutes for elements equal to zero.

Note that after M-1 rounds all elements equal zero or one, with at least one element equaling one, and after M rounds all elements equal zero.

---

Let the array be A with N elements.

For any i, 0 ≤ i ≤ N-1, n = A<sub>i</sub>, A<sub>i</sub> reaches 0 on the n<sup>th</sup> pass through the array. At this point the number of minutes that have elapsed is

Σ<sub>j<i</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, n} + n + Σ<sub>j>i</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, n-1}

*First term*

This term computes the number of minutes contributed by each element j < i, when i > 0. It equals zero if i = 0.

If A<sub>j</sub> > A<sub>i</sub> both A<sub>i</sub> and A<sub>j</sub> are decremented by 1 in every round up to and including the current round n, when A<sub>i</sub> reaches zero. It follows that this element j contributes n minutes to the total for element i.

If A<sub>j</sub> ≤ A<sub>i</sub>, this element would have contributed A<sub>j</sub> minutes for the first A<sub>j</sub> rounds and zero minutes thereafter.

We therefore may write min{A<sub>j</sub>, n} for this term.

*Second term*

The second term is the number of minutes contributed by A<sub>i</sub>. It requires `n` rounds to go to zero, so its contribution to total time is n.

*Third term*

This term computes the number of minutes contributed by each element j > i when i < N-1. It equals zero if i = N-1.

If A<sub>j</sub> ≥ A<sub>i</sub>, both A<sub>j</sub> and A<sub>i</sub> are decremented by 1 in every round up to and including round n-1, but only A<sub>i</sub> is decremented in round n, when it reaches zero. It follows that this element j contributes n-1 minutes to the total for element i.

If A<sub>j</sub> < A<sub>i</sub>, this element j contributed A<sub>j</sub> minutes, as it contributed 1 minute for each of the first A<sub>j</sub> rounds and zero minutes thereafter.

We therefore may write min{A<sub>j</sub>, n-1} for this term.

---

We can apply this to the example given in the question.

A = [3, 1, 2]

**i = 0**

n = A<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>0</sub> = 3

A<sub>0</sub> reaches zero after the following number of minutes.

Σ<sub>j<0</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, n} + 3 + Σ<sub>j>0</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, n-1}

= 0 + 3 + (min{A<sub>1</sub>, 2} + min{A<sub>1</sub>, 2})
= 0 + 3 + (min{1, 2} + min{2, 2})
= 0 + 3 + (1 + 2)
= 6

**i = 1**

n = A<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>1</sub> = 1

A<sub>1</sub> reaches zero after the following number of minutes.

Σ<sub>j<1</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, 1} + 1 + Σ<sub>j>1</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, 1-1}

= min{A<sub>0</sub>, 1} + 1 + min{A<sub>2</sub>, 0}
= min{3, 1} + 1 + min{2, 0}
= 1 + 1 + 0
= 2

**i = 2**

n = A<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>2</sub> = 2

A<sub>2</sub> reaches zero after the following number of minutes.

Σ<sub>j<2</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, 2} + 2 + Σ<sub>j>2</sub>min{A<sub>j</sub>, 2-1}

= (min{A<sub>0</sub>, 2} + min{A<sub>1</sub>, 2}) + 2 + 0
= (min{3, 2} min{1, 2}) + 2 + 0
= (2 + 1) + 2 + 0
= 5

Comment: I am trying to understand the answer and got stuck at statements for first and third terms. `The first term is the number of minutes contributed by each element j < i. For each j that is n if Aj ≥ n and Aj if Aj < n. If i = 0 that term is zero.` Can you please explain little more with example

Comment: learner, my apologies for the multiple edits but I think my answer is stable now. My original answer was correct, just not explained properly. Does it now make sense to you?

Comment: Voted up. I'd review the declarations again. For example, there's an `Aj ≤ Aj`, which is likely a mistake.

Comment: I'd consider adding some proposal for efficiently calculating the sums mentioned.

Comment: Nice observation and description. But with the constraints given I'm not sure this is faster.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, thanks for the typo alert.  As for the efficiency of calculations I don't  see how they can be  much improved  upon, but of course I  would welcome suggestions. After all, the  time efficiency is only O(n) for each element of the array (n being the size of the array).

Comment: It seems to me we can have O(n log n) overall if we record the sums using two trees we build as we traverse once for each direction, looking up and recording the sum for each element.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I don't understand how that would speed the calculations or bring O(n^2) (for the calculations for all elements) down to O(n log n). For n =  Aj, we need to calculate min{Aj, n} for all j < i and min{Aj, n-1} for all j > i, but those N-1 terms (N being the size of A) could be different for every element of A. In particular , would they not all have to be calculated if A contained no duplicates? I see how the calculations for duplicates could be sped.

Comment: Because a tree can return the sum of items over a range of values. If we build the tree as we traverse, we can answer queries in `O(log n)` like "what is the sum of values for items less than or equal to `Ai` that we've seen?" (Meaning `j` is either less than or greater than `i` depending of the traversal direction.) Then for the ones greater than `Ai`, we just multiply by their count.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. This logic works in O(n^2) right if I am not wrong. Can we reduce the time complexity further?

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I don't follow. Could you elaborate on the tree structure?

Comment: learner, yes, O(n^2). I don't see how that can be reduced but @גלעדברקן has made a suggestion that, as you see by my comment above, I don't understand (perhaps you do) and have asked for clarification.

Comment: `sum(min(Aj, n), where j < i)` is the same as `sum(Aj), where Aj ≤ n` plus `n × count-of-Aj-greater-than-n`. The latter we can store for every value in O(n log n). For the former, we build a Fenwick tree using the ordered indexes of A (each element's position in sorted A) as we traverse. For each Aj we pass, we add Aj to its position in the tree (equal to its index in the sorted array). For each `n`, we query the tree for the sum for the range 0 to `n`s index in the sorted array. Similarly for the opposite traversal. (cc @learner)